# Limit-The question asks to find the value of a in the limit.

Tags: limits

[image]

I did the whole sum,and my answer is a=0,2.
And,as the problem asks for the largest value is a=2.
However,the answer is given a=0.
I couldnot understand how it can be.Can any expain?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have correctly worked out the limits:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} = \dfrac{1-a}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

and then you solved the equation $\left(\dfrac{1-a}{2}\right)^{1/2} = \dfrac{1}{4}$ to get $a = 0,2$.

However, you need to remember that $A^B$ is not well defined if $A$ is negative and $B$ is irrational.

If $a > 1$, then $\dfrac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}$ is negative for $x$ near $1$.

Also, there are some values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $1$ such that $\dfrac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}} = 1+\sqrt{x}$ is irrational.

Hence, $\left[\dfrac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}\right]^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}}$ is undefined for some values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\left[\dfrac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}\right]^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}}$ does not exist for $a > 1$.

Comment: But,I couldn't understand why it doesn't exist

Comment: Let's fix $a = 2$. Now, what is the value of that expression when $x = 1.01$? What about $x = 1.001$, or $x = 1.0001$, etc.? Is the expression defined for any of these values of $x$? If not, then the limit doesn't exist since the function isn't defined near $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to go in the same direction as JimmyK4542, around $x=1$, Taylor expansion is $$\dfrac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}=\frac{1-a}{2}-\frac{a+1}{24}  (x-1)^2-\frac{a+1}{720}
   (x-1)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$ which is always negative for any $a>1$.

Comment: But,I couldn't understand why it doesn't exist